# Update column rows by using multiple columns in the dataframe as a key for a nested dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

If I have a data frame with the following structure:

```
Sub-Segment       City       State
Mexico Unmanaged  MEXICO DF  GB
France Unmanaged  PARIS      AB
Canada CCLM       MONTREAL   BC
```

I want to create a new column labeled "Regions" which maps different columns based on sub-segment,city, and state. So to calculate region field for mexico unmanaged we need to only reference the city, however for 'Canada CCLM', the region is calculated by referencing the state column. Therefore I created a nested dictionary.

```
regions={ 'Mexico_Managed':
             {
                 'MEXICO DF': 'Mexico City',
                 'MEXICO':'Mexico City',
             },
          'Canada_CCLM':
              {
                  'BC':'Western Region',
                  'AB':'Western Region',
              }
 }
```

I tried creating the region column like below, but it only mapped the "City" column.

```
df['Region']=df['City'].map(regions['Mexico_Managed'])
```

I now want to be able to update the regions column with values that fall under sub-segment 'canada cclm' and reference the 'state' column in the dataframe. Please help I've been stuck on this forever!!

Comment: Do you have the names of sub-segment which needs to be mapped in what ways? If you have that information, then you should write a callable and use `applymap`

Comment: Yea so Canada CCLM maps region through the "State" column. Would you pls be able to give me an example of how that would look like syntax wise?

Comment: It might be easier to just create a small function for this and then use `apply()`.

Comment: It's straight forward, just compare the value and return the thing you want to for that key in a chain of if else maybe

Comment: @Aditya was trying to avoid using if-else statements but i was able to figure out a work around! Thanks

Comment: Can you share the workaround! Thanks